# SOA record change to use AWS route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain registered with a domain registrar that sets a `SOA` record. I cannot change this `SOA` record. They want a static IP to change this domain record. I want to set records for this domain using `AWS Route 53`.  So I cannot give them an IP.

I  have added the nameservers to the domain given by the zone in AWS. A DNS query returns these new `NS` records. But the `SOA` record still points to a domain server operated by the domain registrar.

A DNS query does not return any other new record I have configured in `Route 53`. I suspect the `SOA` record causes this. I want to narrow down potential causes.

This is the result of `host`:

```
$ host -a <domain>.com
Trying "<domain>.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53801
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;<domain>.com.  IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
<domain>.com. 900   IN  NS  ns-859.awsdns-43.net.
<domain>.com. 900   IN  NS  ns-480.awsdns-60.com.
<domain>.com. 900   IN  NS  ns-1303.awsdns-34.org.
<domain>.com. 900   IN  NS  ns-1579.awsdns-05.co.uk.
<domain>.com. 10800 IN  SOA ns1.<registrar>.com. hostmaster.<registrar>.com. 2018102902 28800 7200 604800 86400

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-859.awsdns-43.net.   2753    IN  A   205.251.195.91

Received 258 bytes from 10.142.1.1#53 in 108 ms
```

Is changing the `SOA` record required to transfer control to `AWS Route 53`

Comment: Have you created hosted Zone on AWS route 53 and then added those name server details to your registered domain panel. If yes then everything should be redirect to AWS Route 53. Because if name server is configured correctly at your domain registrar end then there shouldn't be any issue in forwarding all the records.

Comment: You have confused "changing the authoritative nameservers" (what you should have done) with "changing the NS records" (what you actually did).  This is not about the SOA -- it's about making the original change in the correct place.  Who is your registrar?

Comment: I have created a hosted zone in AWS and added those nameservers to the domain panel. There is still something that is causing the problem. Please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Once you make Route53 DNS as your authoritative name server, then you will be able to edit the SOA records.
Setting Route53 as authoritative name server -

- Create a zone file in route53 for your domain.
- copy the assigned NS records and use them with your domain registrar as authoritative name servers.